PyGObject keyboard bindings seem to perform the same action multiple times
I am trying to bind Control-b and Control-d to the window of a GTK 3 application written in Python. My code is similar (in the important things, the same) as the following:
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk","3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
# Etc.
window=Gtk.Window()
accelerator=Gtk.AccelGroup()
accelerator.connect(Gdk.keyval_from_name("b"),Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK,0,action)
window.add_accel_group(accelerator)
accelerator2=Gtk.AccelGroup()
accelerator2.connect(Gdk.keyval_from_name("d"),Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK,0,action)
window.add_accel_group(accelerator2)
#Etc.
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()

The code seemed to work perfectly, but when I press either ^b or ^d, this seems to trigger the function at least thrice. How can this beaviour be avoided?
